# How to check empty fields AND photo file tipe before registering user? How can I make checkbokes and options required?

Tags: php

I've made a register form on my webiste. I've made name and email required (was easy for me because are text fields), but How can I make country, photo, hobbies required?
Now, I wanna check empty fields AND file type before adding in databases and upload on server. How can I do that? Thanks!

```
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

      if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emptyErr = "   Required field!";   // Error which will be shown if a field is empty
         $name = $_POST['name']; // I put this field to remember user entries if a field is empty
         $email = $_POST['email'];

         } else {
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); // Connect to database
         if (!$con){
             die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
         }

         mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);

          $target = "gallery/profilepictures/";  // Folder for pictures on server

          $pic=(time().'_'.$_FILES['photo']['name']); // I wanna rename the pictures on server. I put time in front of original name

         $hobbies = implode(", ",$_POST['hobbies']);


         $hot = "INSERT INTO table_name (name,email,country,hobbies,default_img)
         VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[country]','$hobbies','$pic')";

         mysql_query($hot,$con);

          //Writes the photo to the server 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target . $pic)) 
        { 

         //Tells you if its all ok 
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
         } 
         else { 

         //Gives and error if its not 
         echo "Oops! Error! Try again!"; 
         } 



      }
      }


      ?>



      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<table style="width:700px">

<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="edit" name="name" size="50" value="<? echo $name?>"><?php  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {echo $emptyErr;}?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="edit" name="email" size="50" value="<? echo $email?>"><?php  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {echo $emptyErr;}?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country:</td><td><select name="country"><option value="USA" selected>USA</option>
                                              <option value="UK">UK</option>
                                              <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
                                              </select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Photo:</td><td><input type="file" name="photo"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Hobbies:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="football">football
                          <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="tennis">tennis
                          <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="carting">carting
                          <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="online games">online games
                          </td></tr>

<tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-custom2 radius fr" value="Adăugați unitatea de cazare &raquo;"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking file size and type you can use something like this,

```
if($_FILES["imagefile"]["size"] >= 2120000) {
  echo "Max size exceeded";
  die();
}else {
    $imageData = @getimagesize($_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"]);

    if($imageData === FALSE || !($imageData[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $imageData[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $imageData[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
      echo "Invalid file type";
      die();
    }
}
```

and if you require only server side checking for empty fields, you can use using

```
if(!empty($PostedData))
  //allow
else
  echo "Field(s) missing."; 
die();
```

Comment: Hi. Where i need to insert code for checking image size / file type in my php code? Like I told you, I wanna check also empty fields and image type in same time, and if everything is ok, all data need to be inserted in databaes, and if not, I want my browser to keep values inserted in fields (and checked in boxes or selected options) and show that Required field messages / or image type error message. Thanks